# Is it possible to go from selenium to beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape a web site. I had to use selenium to pass a login form and I was asking myself whether there was a way to use beautifulSoup to scrape the web site now that I've used selenium?

Comment: Yes it is!
Can you show us what you have done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple combination

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "url"

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
# login/scroll/etc 

full_page = browser.page_source
page_soup = soup(full_page, "html.parser")
# parse/find
```